# convert a character to a vector of numbers

Tags: r

I want to
know if it is possible to convert a string of numbers into a vector of numbers.
For example, if I have a character object

```
x <- "1,2,3,4,5"

length(x)
[1] 1
```

How can I convert `x` to a vector with length 5, so that I can do
numerical operation on it?

So I want

```
length(x)
[1] 5
sum(x)
[1] 15
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! What you will need to do (to help with search terms in the future) is 1) split your string at the comma and then 2) convert your split string objects into numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Look into `?strsplit` -

```
x <- "1,2,3,4,5"

as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x, split = ",")))

[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```